# NPM Package how to export files to use in other project?

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm trying to create a simple npm package so I can share some typescript models between projects.

In my `lib` folder I have these files:

lib/model1.ts

```
export default class Model1 {
    name: string;
}
```

lib/model2.ts

```
export default class Model2 {
    count: number;
}
```

lib/index.ts

```
import Model1 from "./model1";
import Model2 from "./model2";

export = {Model1, Model2};
```

do I need to export my models like this?

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

But when I try to use these models in another project, I get these errors:

```
ERROR in /Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/models/lib/model1.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/models/lib/model1.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/cms/angular/project-fit-cms/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:719:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/cms/angular/project-fit-cms/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
ERROR in /Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/models/lib/model2.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/models/lib/model2.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/cms/angular/project-fit-cms/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:719:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/jonas/Projects/ProjectFit/cms/angular/project-fit-cms/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Comment: I don't know ngtools, but using angular cli https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries or packagr https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr simply works.

Comment: .. using packagr, it looks like this in my procects: `export class MyModel {}` and in index.ts `export * from './mymodel`. I think you need key 'typings: mylib.d.ts' in your package.json to make it work.

Comment: When I export my classes in `index.ts`I still can't do `import Model1 from 'project-name'`. It only works when I do `import Model1 from 'project-name/lib/model1'`. Any Idea?

Comment: You have to use curly braces in your import. w/o braces it's for the 'default' export only and there must be only one default export. I think default exports are not what you want here. so `import * from "./index"` or `import { Model1, Model2 } from "./index"; `should work. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: btw you can shorten your index.ts: `export * from './mymodel';`

Comment: Thanks I got it now!